# Transfer of documents DECWRITE (VMS) to WORD (PC)

Tags: windows, vms

I have a large number of old DECwrite, VAX Document.

Anyone know of how I can get them convert to Word (PC Windows 7)?

Comment: with DecWrite , i can modified txt but, the probleme is how i can modified image inserted in the documents. thank you very much.

Comment: There was a product called ```CDA Converter Library for OpenVMS```, which could convert DECwrite files, that is DDIF Documents, Graphics, etc. to a couple of output formats, including RTF and early MS Word versions. The SPD, http://h30266.www3.hpe.com/PDFs/CDAConverterLibraryV22.pdf, from 1993 is still online. Whether you can get that (and have a VMS system to run them) and whether the old output formats will help you is another question. The format of DECwrite files may be described somewhere, but I doubt that there are other tools to read/export them.

Comment: This is a perl script that is purported to convert DECWRITE to HTML.
http://ftp.lip6.fr/pub/www/tools/translators/decw2html/

Comment: From the perl script _...it does *NOT* process DECwrite .doc (DDIF)
files. First generate an SGML file ..._. That converter is part of the converter library. As I found out today, for OpenVMS/VAX there is a CDACVTLIB022 on the freeware CD (version 6). The freeware CD can be found on the net.